# Reset equation counters with unnumbered sections

Tags: sectioning, equations, enumerate, counters

I would like use:

```
\counterwithin*{equation}{section}
\counterwithin*{equation}{subsection}
```

with `\section*{}` because if the section is not numbered `\counterwithin*{equation}{section}` doesn't work properly, in fact, I'm using this command to do unnumbered sections even in table of contents:

```
\newcommand{\sect}[1] {\section*{#1}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}\addtocounter{section}{1}}
```

But how I said ... I cannot number properly my equations because counters are not restored to a new unnumbered sections.

So much thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counters bound to other counters are reset when the master counter is “stepped” with `\stepcounter`. So I guess that

```
\newcommand{\sect}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{section}\addtocounter{section}{-1}%
  \section*{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
}
```

is what you really want. Unless you want that

```
\section{A}

\sect{B}

\section{C}
```

gives 3 as the section number for “C” like it seems your code does now. In that case,

```
\newcommand{\sect}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{section}%
  \section*{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
}
```

will do.

Comment: Yes, it was just switch `\addtocounter{section}{1}` with `\stepcounter{section}` what I did need. Now works how I want, thank you. :)

Comment: Mainly because I use this

`\newcommand{\seclabel}[1] {\numberwithin{equation}{section}\label{#1}}
\newcommand{\sseclabel}[1] {\numberwithin{equation}{subsection}\label{#1}}` 

To tag equations what I want.

Comment: @JFernan That's a *very* wrong way to go.

Comment: Well, I don't want to enumerate all of my equations, only a few concretely. Only which are in cross-reference by labels, specifically. And this way allow me tag only a few equations with properly numeration (referencing its subsection and section even when section is unnumbered).

Comment: @JFernan It would be much better to open a new question, with a full specification of your needs.

Answer (score 2):

One can argue about this approach:

A reset equation in each `\section*` is without information which section is meant actually, so cross-referencing might become difficult, unless `hyperref` is used with correct linking.

In this solution I applied `\xpretocmd` for `\section` to reset the equation counter (which is probably done anyway), so both for `\section` and `\section*`.

The `sectcont` counter is just for making a unique `hyperref` anchor.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

\counterwithout*{equation}{section}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcounter{sectcont}

\xpretocmd{\section}{%
  \stepcounter{sectcont}%
  \setcounter{equation}{0}%
}{}{}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand{\theHequation}{equation.\thesectcont.\theequation}
}

\begin{document}

In \ref{eqeinsteinagain} we see...

\clearpage

\section*{Foo}

\begin{equation}
  E=mc^2 \label{eqeinstein}
\end{equation}


\begin{equation}
  E=mc^2 \label{eqeinsteinother}
\end{equation}


\clearpage
\section*{Foobar}

\begin{equation}
  E=mc^2 \label{eqeinsteinagain}
\end{equation}


\begin{equation}
  E=mc^2 \label{eqyeteinstein}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Personally, I would not use this approach ....